# How do i get these Postal code characters together?

Tags: python, loops, scripting

So I am trying to generate postal codes in order but the output makes each character separate, is there a way to get them together?

```
for first in range(10):
    for second in range(65,91):
        for third in range(10):
            for fourth in range(10):
                for fifth in range(65,91):
                    for sixth in range(10):
                        print(first,chr(second),third,fourth,chr(fifth),sixth)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think you want to look here:  http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

ex:

```
a = 10
b = 11

'{}{}'.format(a,b)
```

outputs:

```
1011
```

so:

```
for first in range(10):
    for second in range(65,91):
        for third in range(10):
            for fourth in range(10):
                for fifth in range(65,91):
                    for sixth in range(10):
                        print('{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(first,chr(second),third,fourth,chr(fifth),sixth))
```